# Drupal 7 and MathJax

Tags: drupal-7, mathjax

I have tried installing the MathJax module on Drupal 7 and it shows up in the module list, however, it says that "this version of the MathJax module" is not compatible with Drupal 7.

Has anyone tried integrating the MathJax package (e.g, MathJax-v1.0.1a.zip) with Drupal 7, without the use of a module?  If so, how?
Specifically:
Where do you put the MathJax folder (e.g.,sites/all/libraries),
How did you add the functionality to the current template (e.g., themes/[current_theme]/page.tpl.php)
Did you get a rich text editor working with Mathjax?

All ideas are welcome, thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally released a drupal 7.x version of MathJax module...
Feel free to use it: this should be the simplest way to add tex formulas in your drupal website at the moment!

You don't need to download MathJax library anymore, since the module uses mathjax's CDN that allows the user to grab an up to date copy on a server nearby.
And yes, you can integrate it with rich text editors like CKeditor, but you won't see the formula in the editing field, rather the tex formula.

Comment: The module works great. However I haven't been able to integrate it with ckeditor. I added the plugin and dependencies but it does not show up in Plugins list in ckeditor configuration

Comment: I've not been using or developing this module for a while now. You better ask this question on the [module issues list](https://drupal.org/project/issues/mathjax?status=All&categories=All).